# Am I thinking about Callbacks the right way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am so new to node and js that I had no idea about Callbacks and async programming until yesterday, so speak to me like I'm an idiot, 'cos I am...

With the death of mixture.io I thought I would write my own little static site builder. I looked at gulp and grunt but plumped for using [npm as a build tool](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/).

Building the css, minifying, listing etc.. was super easy, but when it came to building the pages, life quickly descended into callback hell.

A bit of reading and I have a start for the page building script:

```
var fm          = require('front-matter'),
    fs          = require('fs'),
    glob        = require('glob'),
    md          = require('marked');

const SEARCHPATH = "content/pages/";


pages = [];



function searchFiles () {
    glob("*.md", { cwd: SEARCHPATH }, readFiles);
}


function readFiles (err, files) {
    if(err) throw err;

    for (var file of files) {
        fs.readFile(SEARCHPATH + file, 'utf8', processFiles);
    }
}


function processFiles(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var attributes = fm(data).attributes;
    var content = md(fm(data).body);

    pages.push(attributes, content);

    applyTemplate(pages);
}

function applyTemplate(pages) {
    console.log(pages);
}

searchFiles();
```

But it looks for all the world like I'm about to descend into daisy-chain hell where each function calls the next, but I can't access the pages variable without doing so.

It all seems a bit off.

Am I thinking about this right? What would be a better way to structure this programmatically?

Thanks as ever Overflowers.

Comment: You've done a pretty good job flattening your structure and making it readable.  Are you creating your own modules?  That is another good thing to do to keep your code clean and separate concerns.

Comment: You don't need each function to call the next and go deeper and deeper into the stack unless you're performing a callback from an async operation. The rest of the code can look however you like.

Comment: Thanks dustmouse. No I'm not. Would you recommend that as the next step? I am sure I'm not thinking about this right: I still want to be able to call searchFiles(), readFiles(), and processFiles() sequentially and be able to access the pages var at any point.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Paul. Aren't glob and fs.readFile async operations? I felt forced to write it that way as I couldn't access the pages var otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You broke out all of the callbacks into function declarations instead of inline expressions so that is already +1, because you have function objects that can be exported and tested.

For this response I'm assuming  the priority is isolated progrmatic unittests, without mocking `require`.  (Which I usually find myself refactoring legacy node.js towards, when I enter a new project).

When I go down this route of nested nested callbacks I think the least easy way to work with is a nested chain of anonymous expressions as callbacks: (in psuedocode)

```
function doFiles() {
   glob('something', function(files) {
      for (f in files) {
         fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
            processFile(data);
         }

      }
   }
}
```

Testing the above programmatically is pretty convoluted.  The only way to do it is to mock requires.  To test that readFile callback is working, you have to control all calls before it!!! Which violates isolation in tests.

The 2nd best approach, imo, is to break out callbacks as you have done.

Which allows better isolation for unittests, but still requires mocking requires for `fs` and `glob`.

The 3rd best approach, imo, is injecting all a functions dependencies, to allow easy configuration of mock objects.  This often looks very weird, but for me the goal is 100% coverage, in isolated unittests without using a mock require library.  It makes it so each function is an isolated object that is easy to test, and configure mock objects for, but often makes calling that function more convoluted!

To achieve this:

```
function searchFiles () {
    glob("*.md", { cwd: SEARCHPATH }, readFiles);
}
```

Would become

```
function searchFiles (getFiles, getFilesCallback) {
    getFiles("*.md", { cwd: SEARCHPATH }, getFilesCallback);
}
```

Then it could be called with

```
searchFiles(glob, readFiles)
```

This looks a little funky because it is a one line function, but illustrates how to inject the dependencies into your functions, so that your tests can configure mock objects and pass them directly to the function.  Refactoring `readFiles` to do this:

```
function readFiles (err, files, readFile, processFileCb) {
    if(err) throw err;

    for (var file of files) {
        readFile(SEARCHPATH + file, 'utf8', processFileCb);
    }
}
```

readFiles takes in a `readFile` method (`fs.readFile` and callback to execute once the file is read. Which allows easy configuration of mock objects in programmatic testing.

Then tests could be, in psuedocode:

```
it('throws err when error is found', function() {
    var error = true;
    assert throws readFiles(error)
});

it('calls readFile for every file in files', function() {
   var files = ['file1'];
   var error = false;
   var readFile = createSpyMaybeSinon?();
   var spyCallback = createSpy();
   readFiles(error, files, readFile, spyCallback);

   assert(readFile.calls.count(), files.length)
   assert readFile called with searchpath + file1, 'utf8', spyCallback
});
```

Once you have these functions that require the client to provide all of the functions dependencies, then they require a dance of creative `bind`ing of callbacks, or small  functional expressions to wrap calls.

The above assumes an endgoal of complete test coverage without mocking requires, which might not be your goal :)

---

A "cleaner" approach imo is just to use promises from the beginnning, which is a wonderful abstraction over asynchronous calls.

Comment: Thanks dm -- My motive was not testing, but elegance of solution. My first attempt was indeed nested nested callbacks as you first point out. Hard on the eye and brain. This daisy chaining of callbacks though seems like there is not enough separation of concerns.

Comment: @Adam imo, code that works is more important than elegant code, but elegant working code is awesome :):) Completely opinion based, the "most elegant" would be a promise based solution

Comment: Very true. Thanks for taking the time to post examples of refactoring -- helps to think things through.